# Is it possible to make an editor the admin of firebase project, when admin account is deleted

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firebase project, which had `1 admin`, and `3 editors`.

The admin of the project has left the company, and company has deleted his email address.

Now firebase project does not have any admin left, and we need to add a new user to this project.

Is there any way `firebase` can update my role. So i become admin and add other users, or any other workaround which allow us to add a new user to the project.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming concern and is more appropriate to be answered by the service provider (Google).